# I would like to know when we want to print only specific columns in pandas how to implement that

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, data-science

```
cols = list(ds.columns.values)
ds = ds[cols[1:3] + cols[5:6] + [cols[9]]]
print(ds)
```

Why did we convert into list in this line `cols = list(ds.columns.values)`?

Answer (score 1):

If ds is a DataFrame from Pandas:

```
type(ds.columns.values)
>>> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

If you sum two differences columns of string or char in numpy:

```
a1 = np.char.array(['a', 'b'])
a2 = np.char.array(['c', 'd'])
a1 + a2
>>> chararray(['ac', 'bd'], dtype='<U2')
```

and not:

```
np.char.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

That why you should convert it in list because:

```
   list1 = ['a','b']
   list2 = ['c','d']
   list1 + list2
   >>> ['a','b','c','d']
```

Remember, pandas.DataFrame need a list of columns, that why you should feed DataFrame a list :

```
panda.DataFrame[[columns1,columns2,columns5,columns9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do slicing for a single `numpy.ndarray` or a single `list`, you would be able to get the dataframe:

```
cols = ds.columns.values      #numpy.ndarray
ds = ds[cols[1:3]]            #ok

cols = ds.columns.tolist()    #list
ds = ds[cols[1:3]]            #ok
```

However, if you use the `+` operator, the behavior is different between `numpy.ndarray` and `list`

```
cols = ds.columns.values           #numpy.ndarray
ds = ds[cols[1:3] + cols[5:6]]     #ERROR

cols = ds.columns.tolist()         #list
ds = ds[cols[1:3] + cols[5:6]]     #ok
```

That is because the `+` operator is "concatenation" for `list`,

whereas for `numpy.ndarray`, the `+` operator is `numpy.add`.

In other words, `cols[1:3] + cols[5:6]` is actually doing `np.add(cols[1:3], cols[5:6])`

Refer to [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.add.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to convert columns into a list:

```py
ds.columns.tolist()
```

But this also seems unnecessary. `ds.columns` returns an `Index`. You can select values from `Index` just like from a normal list, and then append them to each other using `.union`:

```py
cols = ds.columns
ds = ds[cols[1:3].union(cols[5:6]).union(cols[9])]
```

Note that you can use `.iloc` to reach your goal in a more idiomatic way:

```py
ds = ds.iloc[:, [1, 2, 5, 9]]
```

Comment: cols = ds.columns
ds=ds[cols[1:3]+cols[5:6]+[cols[9]]]      This one was not working

Comment: @RathanGanta, yes, sorry. Updated: replaced `+` with [`.union()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html). Now it works. It sorts columns by default but you can pass `sort=False` to `.union()`

Answer (score 0):

`ds.columns` returns an `ndarray`, so slicing it will also produce `ndarray`s. `+` between `ndarray`s behave differently than in between lists

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col2': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col3': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col4': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'col5': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col6': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col7': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col8': [1, 2, 3, 4]})

cols_arr = df.columns.values
cols_list = list(df.columns.values)

print(cols_arr[0:2] + cols_arr[3:4] + [cols_arr[7]])
print(cols_list[0:2] + cols_list[3:4] + [cols_list[7]])
```

Output

```
['col1col4col8' 'col2col4col8']
['col1', 'col2', 'col4', 'col8']
```

When you try to get to access the dataframe `df[cols_arr[0:2] + cols_arr[2:3] + [cols_arr[3]]]` using the first result you will get

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['col1col4col8', 'col2col4col8'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

With the lists `df[cols_list[0:2] + cols_list[3:4] + [cols_list[7]]]` you will get the new dataframe

```
   col1  col2  col4  col8
0     1     1     1     1
1     2     2     2     2
2     3     3     3     3
3     4     4     4     4
```